# Alternate method for typecasting in C?

Tags: c, string

I came across this line in some code and can't find the syntax defined anywhere:

```
*(float *)csCoord.nX = lImportHeight* .04f; /* magic number to scale font size */
```

If I remove the  `f`  from  `.04f`  then the compiler gives a warning about possible data loss due to a conversion from 'double' to 'float'.  I assume the  `f`  is doing some sort of typecasting.

Has anyone seen this before?  Where is this defined in the C standard?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The trailing f indicates to the compiler that it is a float type literal, just like "" indicate a literal string and the L suffix indicates a long int.

The [C++ spec for literals](http://cpp.comsci.us/etymology/literals.html) is the same.

Answer (score 2):

Without "f", the quantity 0.04 is a double. When you multiple lImportHeight with a double, you get another double. Then you store it in a float-sized memory location, losing precision. With "f", 0.04f is a float literal. You multiple lImportHeight with it, and you get a float; then the assignment does not cause loss of precision.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know where it's defined in the standard, but you use an `f` to indicate a float, otherwise the compiler assumes it's a double. Similarly, you can specify an integer to be unsigned by adding a `u`, or a long by `l` (lowercase ell), etc.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly is the problem? Does your compiler choke on .04f? Try

```
(float) .04
```

Comment: No, it compiles fine.  I just had never seen that syntax before and wanted to make sure I understood it.